# Removing multiple sheets after swiping down the last one swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

I currently have two sheets in a row and I want them to be dismissed to the view that called the first sheet once the last sheet is dismissed by the user. I am open to not pulling up views as sheets its just the way I learned how to easily pull up new views.

BookView is what I want to be returned after the PickDefinition sheet view has been dismissed.

BookView pulls up AddWord as a sheet.

AddWord is pulled up as a sheet and then in it PickDefinition is pulled up as a sheet.

After PickDefinition is dismissed I would like for it to go back to the BookView

```
struct BookView: View {
    @ObservedObject var book: Book
    @State var addingWord = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(Array(zip(book.words, book.definitions)), id: \.self.0) { (word, definition) in
                Text("\(word) - \(definition)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            DB_Manager().openBook(name: book.name, book: self.book)
        })
        .navigationBarTitle("\(book.name)")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            self.addingWord = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
        ).sheet(isPresented: $addingWord) {
            AddWord(book: self.book)
        }
    }
}


struct AddWord: View {
    @ObservedObject var book: Book
    @StateObject var currentArray = SaveArray()
    @State var addingDefinition = false
    @State var word = ""
    @State var definition = ""
    @State var allDefinitions: [String] = []

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Word: ", text: $word)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add word")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add") {
                if self.word != "" {
                    book.words.append(self.word)

                    getDef(self.word, book, currentArray)
                    addingDefinition = true
                }
            }).sheet(isPresented: $addingDefinition) {
                
                PickDefinition(definitions: currentArray, book: book, word: self.word)
            }

        }
    }



struct PickDefinition: View {
    @ObservedObject var definitions: SaveArray
    var book: Book
    var word: String
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0 ..< definitions.currentArray.count) { index in
                        Button("\(self.definitions.currentArray[index])", action: {
                            print("hello")
                            DB_Manager().addWords(name: self.book.name, word: self.word, definition: self.definitions.currentArray[index])
                            book.definitions.append(self.definitions.currentArray[index])
                            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Choose")
            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `addingWord` into the `AddWord` view, and then into the `PickDefinition` view, using `Binding`. When `PickDefinition` disappears, set the passed property to `false` to hide the `AddWord` sheet.

```swift
struct BookView: View {
  var body: some View {
    // ...
    .sheet(isPresented: $addingWord) {
      AddWord(book: self.book, presentAddingWord: $addingWord)
    }
  }
}

struct AddWord: View {
  @Binding var presentAddingWord: Bool
  // ...
  var body: some View {
    // ...
    .sheet(isPresented: $addingDefinition) {
      PickDefinition(/* ... */, presentAddingWord: $presentAddingWord)
    }
  }
}

struct PickDefinition: View {
  @Binding var presentAddingWord: Bool
  // ...
  var body: some View {
    // ...
    .onDisappear {
      presentAddingWord = false
    }
  }
}
```